# Multiple Views, Which is better UITableView, UIView or UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, multiple-views

### Requirement:

iPad application:

Show custom controls in a list, controls are like "Select File", "Image Edit", "Video Edit", "Radio Group", "Checkbox", "Textbox with header", "Panel", "Tabs", "Signature".

Right now i manage custom controls in a `UITableView`.

Each controls has properties (enble, hidden, editable, secure,  color, font, text etc.). Properties can be change by select control from list (tap on row of `UITableView`), And it will open a property inspector view related to specific control.

### Challenge:

Its working perfectly till i have single control for a row. Now i have a requirement to group this controls and display in a single row.

Its difficult to manage a group of controls in a row. Which is better approach to follow?

1. Use `UITableView` add group of controls in this and then add `UITableView` as a cell
2. Use of `UIView`
3. `UICollectionView`

Comment: I decided to go with `UITableView` and add group in `UITableViewCell`. Please give your opinion if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posting self answer** because the approach for above is now success fully working. Tested for all possible combination for a month.

I continue with `UITableView` and add custom views in `UITableViewCell` all events are manage in respective views by delegates.

The complex part in which I have to manage group of controls. For that i created one more `UITableView` and add it in main table (Here my requirement is not to go for further grouping so it is vital to take `UITableView`).

**Performance:**

Tested for performance as well. For device below then iOS 7.0 some times show lag on scrolling. For iOS 7.0 and above devices it works smooth.

Appreciate more answers from other, If any one have gone situation like this.