# UITableView inside a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, subview, typeahead

#### Generally:

Is it OK to add a `UITableView` as a subview of another `UITableView`? Or, should I create a `UIView` and add each `UITableView` to it?

#### Specifically:

For a `ComposeTableViewController` with a typeahead, like in the iPhone's native Mail app, which approach would you recommend and why?

Note: I prefer to construct things 100% programmatically (no Interface Builder).

1. Subclass `UITableViewController`.

   Then, to show the typeahead results, create and add a `resultsTableView` as a subview of `self.tableView` positioned directly underneath the the cell (of `self.tableView`) with the typeahead text field.

   The nice thing about this approach is that `resultsTableView` scrolls with `self.tableView` automatically.

   But, is it OK to add a `UITableView` as a subview of another `UITableView`?
2. Subclass `UIViewController`.

   Create and add `tableView` (custom property) as a subview of `self.view`.

   Create and add `resultsTableView` also as a subview of `self.view`.

   The annoying thing about this approach is that I have to reposition `resultsTableView` manually anytime `self.tableView` scrolls.

I think I'd prefer approach 1, but adding a `UITableView` as a subview of another `UITableView` just seems smelly to me.

Comment: I've been wondering... Why would you want to put a TableView inside a TableView? Not that anything's wrong with it but I'm just really curious about why you would use that...

Answer (score 1):

TableViews cannot have subviews.  You can try adding a tableview as the view of a TableViewCell, but then you have to ask yourself how it would scroll, if you tried scrolling in the subtableview would it scroll the child tableview or the parent tableview?  It is much easier to present multiple tableviews within a view.  This can be done easily by setting your custom viewcontroller as the datasource of both tableviews contained within its view and then comparing the tableview pointer that is sent as a parameter of the datasource method to the two tableview pointers that are IVars of your custom view controller.

Comment: Most views can have subviews. UITableViews definitely CAN have subviews. As for figuring out which table to scroll, you can override the scroll view's scrolling delegate methods to redirect certain scrolls if you want. But the rest of your points are good - generally it is better to find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Hold stuff like this in a container. Create a container view controller which only does typeahead. This container view controller will hold your main table view controller (and its table view) and it will hold the typeahead view controller (and its view).

It will keep the logic needed for the typeahead out of your main table view and as a bonus you might end up with a reusable typeahead container which could be applied to other views.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is good to go for adding `UITableView` in as a cell of another `UITableView`.**

I had one issue and posted a question

[Multiple Views as subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881281/multiple-views-which-is-better-uitableview-uiview-or-uicollectionview)

And requirement was like a group of controls with list of other controls. I thought that time that it will be messy if i'm going to add `UITableView` as a cell of `UITableView`.

What i found that... Boy !! it's how iOS meant to be. There is no any lag while doing this.

Tested for below functionalities:

1. Scrolls like a charm
2. Separate delegates called for each
3. Reordering of both `UITableView` cell
4. Swipe and remove cell
5. Runtime datasource update for both `UITableView` and reload both at the same time.

There is no any reason not to add subview `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it is against the principle of MVC. You will be setting the delegate of a view to another view which is wrong.